# Fetching all the values for keys matching a regular expression

Tags: ruby, key-value-store

I'm looking for a Ruby **in-memory key-value store** that allows me to select all values for the keys that match a regular expression.

I have looked online but I can't find something the does what I need.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

**Update**

After reviewing my question I noticed I wasn't probably very clear so, also because someone of you guys asked got it, here an example. 
I'm currently using [Daybreak](http://propublica.github.io/daybreak/) in my app so I use it for the example but it does not work.

```
require 'daybreak'

  db = Daybreak::DB.new "example.db"
  db['prefix_foo'] = 'first'
  db['prefix_bar'] = 'second'
  db['doo'] = 'third'

   db.magic('prefix') #=> [ db['prefix_foo'], db['prefix_bar']]
Or
   db.magic('prefix') #=> ['prefix_foo', 'prefix_bar']
```

I'd rather not to use a "naked" hash.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Example please, I think, I know the answer. But I am not sure, if that's the answer you are looking for or not..

Comment: You can do hash.select{|k, v| k[regex] }.values

Comment: My apologies, didn't know my question violated SO rules. Please, delete it. Thanks god your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = {:make => "bmw", :year => "2003"}
str.select{|k,v| k =~ /ak/} 
#=> {:make=>"bmw"}

str.select{|k,v| k =~ /ak/}.values  #=> get only values
#=> ["bmw"]
```